# $X$ is a topological space s.t. every continuous $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is bounded. Is X compact?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

A well-known basic topological result is that if $X$ is a compact topological space, then every continuous function $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is bounded.
That raises the natural question - is the converse also true? Or maybe there exists a non-compact space that still holds that property, "every continuous real function is bounded"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Possibly surprisingly, the converse is not true. (However, it **is** true if we additionaly assume that $X$ is metric.)

To see that, let $\mathbb{R_{coco}}$ be the set $\mathbb{R}$ with the [cocountable topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocountable_topology). (coco stands for cocountable, of course!). It is not compact: for example, let $A=\mathbb{R_{coco}}-\mathbb{N}$.
Then $$A, A\cup\left \{ 1 \right \}, A\cup\left \{ 1,2 \right \}, ...$$
is an open cover with no finite subcover.

However, we'll show that every continuous function $f:\mathbb{R_{coco}}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is constant (and in particular bounded).
Let $x_0\in \mathbb{R_{coco}}$ be arbitrary. Let $U\subset \mathbb{R}$ be an arbitrary open neigborhood of $f(x_0)$ in $\mathbb{R}$. $f^{-1}(U)$ is not empty, but it is open in the cocountable topology and hence cocountable.
As a result, if $V$ is an open set (in $\mathbb{R}$) who's disjoint from $U$, then it's inverse image is at most countable, but still open in the coco topology, hence empty. Therefore $Im (f)\subseteq U$. But this is true for every $U$ who's an open neighborhood of $f(x_0)$. Therefore $Im (f)=\left \{ f(x_0) \right \}$ and $f$ is constant.

Comment: What was the purpose of posting this question when you know the answer.

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik "Answer your own question – share your knowledge, Q&A-style" - appears at the bottom of every question you ask. I decided to try it for once.

Comment: I have not seen/observed that. Now I saw that. Fair enough.

Answer (score 6):

The OP may not care anymore, but...

Here is a class of spaces I use frequently in class, merely because they often serve as quick counterexamples to questions like this one.  Also, they are incredibly easy to understand for beginners.

Let $X$ be any set and fix once and for all a point $a \in X$.  Put a topology on $X$ by declaring $U \subseteq X$ to be open if and only if $a \in U$ (or $U = \varnothing$).  This is clearly a topology on $X$; call the resulting space $X_a$.

For this question, it is a simple yet great exercise in definitions to prove that any continuous function $f: X_a \to Y$ is constant if $Y$ is Hausdorff.  Moreover, $X_a$ is compact if and only if $|X|$ is finite. So, when $Y = \mathbb{R}$, this squashes all hope for your converse to be true, as being constant is a pretty severe way of being bounded.

Comment: I like it! But you might want: "Let $X$ be any set and fix once..." +1

Comment: @MikeMathMan :   Oh, you are definitely correct.  Will fix.

Answer (score 5):

A space $X$ such that every function $fX \to \mathbb{R}$ is bounded is called "pseudocompact", and compact spaces are always pseudocompact. The reverse need not hold, even for nice spaces. The most classical example is $\omega_1$, the first uncountable ordinal in the order topology.

This space is pseudocompact, locally compact, hereditarily normal and *not* compact.

We can also find topological groups that can serve as examples, like

$\{f: \mathbb{R} \to \{0,1\}: |f^{-1}[\{1\}]| \le \aleph_0\}$ in the product topology inherited from $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{R}}$, with pointwise addition mod $2$ as operation.